custom zoom-in zoom-out buttons in leaflet using pico.css
Coming from this answer to customization of marker in leafleat: remove blue background from markers, now i have the following problem:
.html file:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="it">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@picocss/pico@1/css/pico.min.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.4/dist/leaflet.css"

    integrity="sha256-p4NxAoJBhIIN+hmNHrzRCf9tD/miZyoHS5obTRR9BMY="
    crossorigin=""/>

    <title>TITLE</title>
</head>
<body>             
        <div id="map"></div>
            <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.4/dist/leaflet.js"
            integrity="sha256-20nQCchB9co0qIjJZRGuk2/Z9VM+kNiyxNV1lvTlZBo="
            crossorigin=""></script>

            <script src="mapscript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

style.css:
#map { height: 500px; }

[role=button],button,input[type=button],input[type=reset],input[type=submit]{
    --background-color:none;
    --border-color:none;
    }

[role=button]:is([aria-current],:hover,:active,:focus),button:is([aria-current],:hover,:active,:focus),input[type=button]:is([aria-current],:hover,:active,:focus),input[type=reset]:is([aria-current],:hover,:active,:focus),input[type=submit]:is([aria-current],:hover,:active,:focus){
    --background-color:none;
    --border-color:none;
    }

.leaflet-control-zoom-in, .leaflet-control-zoom-out {
    background-image: none;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    border: none;
}

.leaflet-control-zoom-in {
    background-image: url('./immagini/plus-circle-svgrepo-com.svg');
}

.leaflet-control-zoom-out {
    background-image: url('./immagini/minus-circle-svgrepo-com.svg');
}

I can't understand how to remove background from zoom-in and zoom-out buttons as i'm using svg files with transparent background.



To fix the zoom-in and zoom-out buttons weird appearance after using pico.css, you can use the following line on the buttons
padding: 0px 0px;

so the trick is to apply the following after the pico.css
<style>

[role=button],button,input[type=button],input[type=reset],input[type=submit]{
    --background-color:none;
    --border-color:none;
    padding: 0px 0px;
 
}

[role=button]:is([aria-current],:hover,:active,:focus),button:is([aria-current],:hover,:active,:focus),input[type=button]:is([aria-current],:hover,:active,:focus),input[type=reset]:is([aria-current],:hover,:active,:focus),input[type=submit]:is([aria-current],:hover,:active,:focus){
    --background-color:none;
    --border-color:none;
}

</style>

and the whole code will be (as an example) :
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <base target="_top">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
    <title>Quick Start - Leaflet</title>

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@picocss/pico@1/css/pico.min.css">

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="pico.css">

    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="docs/images/favicon.ico" />

<style>

[role=button],button,input[type=button],input[type=reset],input[type=submit]{
    --background-color:none;
    --border-color:none;
padding: 0px 0px;;
 
}

[role=button]:is([aria-current],:hover,:active,:focus),button:is([aria-current],:hover,:active,:focus),input[type=button]:is([aria-current],:hover,:active,:focus),input[type=reset]:is([aria-current],:hover,:active,:focus),input[type=submit]:is([aria-current],:hover,:active,:focus){
    --background-color:none;
    --border-color:none;
}

</style>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.4/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha256-p4NxAoJBhIIN+hmNHrzRCf9tD/miZyoHS5obTRR9BMY=" crossorigin=""/>


    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.4/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha256-20nQCchB9co0qIjJZRGuk2/Z9VM+kNiyxNV1lvTlZBo=" crossorigin=""></script>

    <style>
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
        }
        .leaflet-container {
            height: 400px;
            width: 600px;
            max-width: 100%;
            max-height: 100%;
        }
    </style>

    
</head>
<body>



<div id="map" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>
<script>

    const map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

    const tiles = L.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        maxZoom: 19,
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
    }).addTo(map);

//  const marker = L.marker([51.5, -0.09]).addTo(map);


const LeafIcon = L.Icon.extend({
        options: {
//          shadowUrl: '',
            iconSize:     [32, 32],
//          shadowSize:   [50, 64],
            iconAnchor:   [22, 94],
//          shadowAnchor: [4, 62],
            popupAnchor:  [-3, -76]
        }
    });

    const greenIcon = new LeafIcon({iconUrl: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/library_maps.png'});

    const mGreen = L.marker([51.5, -0.09], {icon: greenIcon}).bindPopup('StackOverflow.com is good').addTo(map);

</script>

</body>
</html>

See the result of the above

if you click the marker, the above code will display:

Feel free to further modify the above code to suit your own needs.
Enjoy.
